# How to find an inverse of this type of functions?

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ Be functions from where $x,y$ are whole numbers. ($Z^2 \to Z^2$)

$F(x,y) = (x+3y,x+5y)$

$G(x,y) = (2x+3y,3x+5y)$

**The question:**

One of these functions has an inverse, Prove it and find its inverse functions.

**My question:**

I don't really know how to decide which one is inversible. I tried to show that $f(x,y)$ is not surjective but with no success.

Also, I don't know how to find the inverse of a function like this.

Can someone hint me to the solution? (I want to solve it myself). Maybe through an example or something.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider writing the equations using matrices and try to invert the matrices

Comment: Great question, and some good answers below, based on @J.W.Tanner's comment. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 6):

If the function
$(ax+by, cx+dy)$
is invertable,
then,
given $(u, v)$
you can solve

$ax+by = u\\
cx+dy = v
$

for $x$ and $y$.

This means that the determinant

$\bigg|
\begin{array}\\
a & b\\
c & d 
\end{array}
\bigg|
$

is non-zero.

So,
what are the determinants of
the two systems?

(added a bit later)

I realized that you want integers.
So the determinant
has to be
$\pm 1$.

Check that, too.

Answer (score 3):

For the first function for example, you have $$F(x,y)=(u,v)=(x+3y,x+5y)$$
This can be written as

$u=x+3y$ and $v=x+5y$

So the inverse $F^{-1}$ of $F$ must have the property $F^{-1}(u,v)=(x,y)$ i.e. to get $F^{-1}$ you have to find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 0):

An example : consider the function $h : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ given by $h(x,y) = (3x+y,5x+2y)$. It is easy to see that $h$ is injective. Now, we claim that $h$ is surjective. To see this, given $(u,v) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ we need to find $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $(u,v) = h(x,y)$.

Observe that the latter reduces to solve a system of linear equations:
$$\begin{cases}
3x+y = u \\ 5x+2y = v
\end{cases}$$
Solving this, we obtain that $(x,y) = (2u-v,-5u+3v)$, which means that
$$h(2u-v,-5u+3v) = (u,v).$$
Defining $g : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ by $g(u,v) = (2u-v,-5u+3v)$ the latter can be rewritten as $h(g(u,v)) = (u,v)$, but this means precisely that the inverse of $h$ is $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The inverses of $\pmatrix{1&&3\\1&&5}$ and $\pmatrix{2&&3\\3&&5}$ are

$\pmatrix{\frac52&&-\frac32\\-\frac12&&\frac12}$ and $\pmatrix{5&&-3\\-3&&2},$ respectively.